# appcelerator studio buildToolsVersion 24.0.2 error?

Tags: android, appcelerator

i am trying to run/package `Android` application using `appcelerator` studio , unfortunately i am having error by `buildToolsVersion 24.0.2`

```
[INFO] : Running dexer: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "Xmx1024M" "-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit" "-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/jack/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools" "-jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.3/lib/dx.jar" "dex" "-output=/Users/jack/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/Dallini/build/android/bin/classes.dex" "/Users/jack/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/Dallini/build/android/bin/classes" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/lib/titanium-verify.jar" "/Users/jack/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/Dallini/modules/android/com.boxoutthinkers.reqstorageperm/0.1/ti-android-requeststoragepermission.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/3.4.1/cloudpush.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/3.4.1/lib/aps-cloudpush-1.1.4.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/3.4.1/lib/google-play-services-base.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/3.4.1/lib/google-play-services-gcm.jar" "/Users/jack/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/Dallini/modules/android/ti.permissions/0.5/tipermissions.jar" "/Users/jack/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/Dallini/modules/android/ti.imagefactory/2.2.2/imagefactory.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.map/2.3.10/map.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.map/2.3.10/lib/google-play-services-map.jar" "/Users/jack/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/Dallini/modules/android/bencoding.alarmmanager/0.123/alarmmanager.jar" "/Users/jack/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/Dallini/modules/android/com.mykingdom.pdfreader/1.1/pdfreader.jar" "/Users/jack/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/Dallini/modules/android/ti.draggable/1.2.3/draggable.jar" "/Users/jack/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/Dallini/modules/android/dk.napp.drawer/1.1.6/nappslide.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/facebook/5.2.0/facebook.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/facebook/5.2.0/lib/AudienceNetwork-fb-4.7.0.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/facebook/5.2.0/lib/bolts-android-1.2.1.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/facebook/5.2.0/lib/facebook_sdk_470.jar" "/Users/jack/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/Dallini/modules/android/com.shareourideas.locale/0.1/locale.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/kroll-v8.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-analytics.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/aps-analytics.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-android.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/jaxen-1.1.1.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/kroll-common.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/titanium.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-filesystem.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-app.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-ui.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-media.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-appcompat.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/android-support-v4.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-cardview.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/cardview-v7-23.0.1.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-locale.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-network.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-xml.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-utils.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-geolocation.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-accelerometer.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-contacts.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-map.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-calendar.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-gesture.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-platform.jar" "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-database.jar"
[ERROR] : Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR] : 
[ERROR] : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
[ERROR] : at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[ERROR] : at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
[ERROR] : at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
[ERROR] : at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
[ERROR] : at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
[ERROR] : at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
[ERROR] : at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[ERROR] : at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR] : at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[ERROR] : at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
[ERROR] : at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
[ERROR] : at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
[ERROR] : at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

after some research i found that i have to downgrade the build tool to 23 , and i don't know how to do in this studio , any adivce is very much appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a big task to downgrade build tools, all you need is just to delete version 24 folder from Android SDK.

Refer my screenshot. It's from MacOS, but still structure remains same for all OS.[image]

You can see that there is no 24 folder in build-tools folder, so remove everything for version 24 until we have a Ti SDK to support it.

Comment: u just made my day